# Capturing items from multiple lists using a single regex

Tags: javascript, regex, list, replace, capture-group

My input looks like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. _**4**,**7**,**13** Nullam suscipit orci sit amet feugiat facilisis. Curabitur eget 8 ligula malesuada, vehicula 3,6 quam sit amet, _**5** tempor velit.

I need to capture every number that's in a comma-separated list preceded by `_`, individually and using a single regex.

In other words, I need the bolded numbers above:

> [4, 7, 13, 5]

I've been trying again and again to make this work without success. I'd like to know if this is even possible before forfeiting and going with multiple expressions.

I'm looking for a solution in Javascript, but obviously any pointer will help.

Comment: But `5` isn't in a comma-separated list...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? A jsfiddle would be even better.

Comment: @Evilzebra I haven't posted what I've tried because frankly, I couldn't really get much farther than a basic expression. Here is the closest I got to the requirement though (I'm still capturing that 6 in the second list): http://regex101.com/r/nX9hP9/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in Javascript:

```
var input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 4,7,13 Nullam suscipit orci sit amet feugiat facilisis. Curabitur eget 8 ligula malesuada, vehicula 3,6 quam sit amet, 5 tempor velit.';

var matches = [];
input.replace(/_(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\b/g, function($0, $1) { 
      matches = matches.concat( $1.split(/,/g) ); return $1; } );

console.log(matches);
//=> ["4", "7", "13", "5"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That seems to be the most efficient way to do it. I wanted to make sure that capturing the numbers through the regex alone wasn't possible before doing it "manually".

Comment: I believe there is no alternative other than using a callback function like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
(_\d+(?:,\d+)*)
```

Try this.Grab the captures.Then split by `,`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/23